# Optimal compounding rate for minibatches SpaCy NER model

Tags: natural-language

I am trying to train a blank NER model using SpaCy. I have 500000 samples of text data and want to train 9 entities. This is the configuration for the mini-batches I am using:

```
batches = minibatch(data, size=compounding(1, 16, 1.001))
```

This parameters are the recommended for a NER model by SpaCy. But its really slow.

My question is, should I increase significantly the max batch size (up to 1024, 2048..) along with the compounding rate (1.001 above) in order to speed up the process? Would this affect the model performance by much?